# Access to AmazonWorkspaces

Tags: amazon-workspaces

I am setting up an Amazon Workspace instance, and need to provide the user with a password to log in. The invite email only contains the registration code.

How do I set up a user password to enable the user to login into Amazon workspace only (no console access)?

I am creating an AmazonWorkspace from a custom bundle, and adding a user to Simple AD.

Comment: Side-note: Amazon WorkSpaces requires an Active Directory service to manage authentication. See also: [Get Started with Amazon WorkSpaces Quick Setup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/getting-started.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, thanks, I have read this document but it doesn't address the situation.
Editing the question above to add details.

Comment: The WorkSpace is not associated with an IAM User. It is associated with the identity selected from Active Directory (or AWS Directory Service) when the WorkSpace is created. WorkSpaces users do *not* authenticate with an IAM identity.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein how can I manage users in AWS directory without installing additional tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the user password for AmazonWorkspace, set user password on the WorkMail application for that user.   Directory service manages users for both AmazonWorkspaces and WorkMail, and the password is shared across.

The user must exist, but can be disabled. Email address can be anything, in my case users do not use AWS email.

Users defined in IAM are not visible from AmazonWorkspaces and WorkMail. If a user has console, S3, ec2, etc.. access in addition to Workspace, they would need to be defined separately in IAM and Directory.

[image: WorkMail users screen]

Answer (score 0):

Individual workspaces created in Amazon WorkSpaces are assigned to, and used by, individuals who are defined in a **Directory**.

From [Manage Directories for Amazon WorkSpaces](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/manage-workspaces-directory.html):

> Amazon WorkSpaces uses a directory to store and manage information for your WorkSpaces and users. You can use one of the following options:
>
> - **AD Connector** — Use your existing on-premises Microsoft Active Directory. Users can sign into their WorkSpaces using their on-premises credentials and access on-premises resources from their WorkSpaces.
> - **Microsoft AD** — Create a Microsoft Active Directory hosted on AWS.
> - **Simple AD** — Create a directory that is compatible with Microsoft Active Directory, powered by Samba 4, and hosted on AWS.
> - **Cross trust** — Create a trust relationship between your Microsoft AD directory and your on-premises domain.

If you have your own Active Directory, then use it. If you do not have Active Directory, the simplest option is to choose **Simple AD**, which is a Active Directory-compatible Samba service. ([Charges apply](https://aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/pricing/))

The user is selected when the WorkSpace is created. Amazon WorkSpaces will send a **registration code** to the end user. The end user then uses an [Amazon WorkSpaces client](https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/) to connect with the service. They provide the Registration Code to configure the client (once only), then login with their AD credentials.

Comment: I have a Simple AD set up on AWS, and user records are added there with user@corp.aws.com email address. As far as I can tell, email does not get delivered.

Comment: Did you then create a new WorkSpace and assign it to the user in Simple AD? You can select the WorkSpace and choose **Invite User** to view the registration code.

Comment: yes, I created a new WorkSpace and assigned it to the user in Simple AD. 

I have the registration code. After user enters the registration code, they are asked to login with their AD  credentials, including AD password.

Comment: Why are you using an email address of `@corp.aws.com`? That doesn't sound like a real email address. Anyway, can they login to WorkSpaces and start using it?

Comment: I put in a real, working email address when creating a user. 
Actually, you are right, the @corp.aws.com is the email that shows up in IAM, not in AD.
The user tried logging into the workspace with email credentials, but that did not work. They also followed the 'Forgot password' instructions, and never received the email with recovery link.

Comment: How can I see user records in Simple AD?

Comment: Doc: [Add Users and Groups (Simple AD and Microsoft AD)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/creating_ad_users_and_groups.html)